# Horizontal scrollbar for textbox

Tags: css

Is it possible to add a horizontal scrollbar to a text box that works in all browsers?
Currently if the text value is bigger than the size of the text box you have to highlight the text and move cursor to the right to see the rest of the text. I'd like user to have a scrollbar to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the user’s going to be entering a lot of text, maybe use a `<textarea>` element instead of `<input type="text">`.